# Get substrings from a string by matching characters

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the prices from a string list that I have.

These is a sample of `PriceList`:

```
PriceList = ['Weekly:$3,600.00\n\nMonthly:$15,120.00',
             'Daily:$3,000.00\n\nWeekly:$8,400.00\n\nMonthly:$33,600.00',
             'Daily:$1,800.00\n\nWeekend:$2200.00',
             'Day:$3,600.00\n\nWeekly:$6,000.00\n\nMonthly:$24,000.00']
```

From the `PriceList`, I want to extract the `MonthlyPrice` and `DailyPrice`.

If `MonthlyPrice` is not present then it is `NA`.

I tried this code:

```
for item in PriceList:
    if item.find("Monthly")!= -1:
        MonthlyPrice = (item[8:])
    if item.find("Yearly")!= -1:
        YearlyPrice = (item[7:])
    if item.find("Weekly")!= -1:
        WeeklyPrice = (item[7:])
```

But it is not working, Kindly help me with this.

Expected Result

`print(WeeklyPrice)` for the 1st example on the list will give you `$3600.00`
`print(DailyPrice)`  for the 1st example on the list will give you - `NA`.

Comment: What's with the lonely `"\n\nWeekend"` in the last list?

Comment: your code tries to find also `Yearly` and `Weekly` when you just *want to extract the MonthlyPrice and DailyPrice*, why?

Comment: @timgeb Fixed it on the question now.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I was just trying to give an example. I need the Yearly, Monthly, Weekly and Daily Price.

Comment: ok, post the final expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of awkwardly parsing that lonely string wrapped in a list, build a dictionary.

```
>>> prices = ['Daily:$3,000.00\n\nWeekly:$8,400.00\n\nMonthly:$33,600.00']
>>> prices = dict(time_price.split(':') for time_price in prices[0].split())
>>> prices
{'Monthly': '$33,600.00', 'Daily': '$3,000.00', 'Weekly': '$8,400.00'}
```

From here it's child's play to extract whatever you want.

```
>>> prices['Daily']
'$3,000.00'
>>> prices.get('NotFound', 'NA')
'NA'
```

Note that if you plan to do any arithmetic with the prices in the future converting them to `float` values is a good idea.

```
>>> prices = {k:float(v[1:].replace(',', '')) for k,v in prices.items()}
>>> prices
{'Monthly': 33600.0, 'Daily': 3000.0, 'Weekly': 8400.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for item in PriceList:
    for line in item.splitlines():
        if line.startswith('Daily:'):
            DailyPrice = line[len('Daily:'):]
        if line.startswith('Weekly:'):
            WeeklyPrice = line[len('Weekly:'):]
        if line.startswith('Monthly:'):
            MonthlyPrice = line[len('Monthly:'):]
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution with [`regex.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.findall) function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

price_list = ['Weekly:$3,600.00\n\nMonthly:$15,120.00',
              'Daily:$3,000.00\n\nWeekly:$8,400.00\n\nMonthly:$33,600.00',
              'Daily:$1,800.00\n\nWeekend:$2200.00',
              'Day:$3,600.00\n\nWeekly:$6,000.00\n\nMonthly:$24,000.00']

base_dict = {'Yearly': 'NA', 'Monthly': 'NA', 'Weekly': 'NA', 'Daily': 'NA'}
pat = re.compile('(?:(Yearly|Monthly|Weekly|Daily):(\$[\d.,]+))')

for p_str in price_list:
    result_d = dict(base_dict)
    result_d.update(pat.findall(p_str))
    print('Yearly: {Yearly}, Monthly: {Monthly}, Weekly: {Weekly}, Daily: {Daily}'.format(**result_d))
```

The output:

```
Yearly: NA, Monthly: $15,120.00, Weekly: $3,600.00, Daily: NA
Yearly: NA, Monthly: $33,600.00, Weekly: $8,400.00, Daily: $3,000.00
Yearly: NA, Monthly: NA, Weekly: NA, Daily: $1,800.00
Yearly: NA, Monthly: $24,000.00, Weekly: $6,000.00, Daily: NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this which first creates a temporary `prices` dictionary from each string of data in `PriceList`, and then uses the dictionary [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to determine if specific values were in the string. Looking up things in dictionaries is very fast, so this implementation approach is also fairly efficient as well.

```
PriceList = ['Weekly:$3,600.00\n\nMonthly:$15,120.00',
             'Daily:$3,000.00\n\nWeekly:$8,400.00\n\nMonthly:$33,600.00',
             'Daily:$1,800.00\n\nWeekend:$2200.00',
             'Day:$3,600.00\n\nWeekly:$6,000.00\n\nMonthly:$24,000.00']

for data in PriceList:
    prices = dict(item.split(':') for item in data.split('\n\n'))
    MonthlyPrice = prices.get("Monthly", "NA")
    YearlyPrice = prices.get("Yearly", "NA")
    WeeklyPrice = prices.get("Weekly", "NA")
    print('MonthlyPrice: {:<10}, YearlyPrice: {:<10}, WeeklyPrice: {:<10}'.format(
            MonthlyPrice, YearlyPrice, WeeklyPrice))
```

Output:

```
MonthlyPrice: $15,120.00, YearlyPrice: NA        , WeeklyPrice: $3,600.00
MonthlyPrice: $33,600.00, YearlyPrice: NA        , WeeklyPrice: $8,400.00
MonthlyPrice: NA        , YearlyPrice: NA        , WeeklyPrice: NA
MonthlyPrice: $24,000.00, YearlyPrice: NA        , WeeklyPrice: $6,000.00
```